# Read amplitudes of (MP3/WAV) using MCI Command

Tags: .net, c++-cli, mci

A couple of friends and I are working on a soundboard and we would like to implement
a waveform-generator, for which we need information regarding the amplitudes of a sound
at specific points.
I would be so thankful for any idea on how to get this information.

We are using C++/CLI and MCI Command. So, is it possible to get the values of the amplitudes of a sound file using MCI Command?

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798683(v=vs.85).aspx maybe sending a "status alias xy" can help.

Comment: From here I prefer "level - Returns the current PCM audio sample value."